# Passing a self-reference to a new object in Java

Tags: java, object

Is it possible to instantiate an object and pass a reference to that new object itself as one of the parameters without modifying the code in the class?
Example:

```
SuperObject obj = new SuperObject(<"pointer to this new SuperObject">);
```

Thanks!

edit:EMPHASIS: I do not want to modify the code inside the class. The this operator does not help!

Comment: Hmmm.  Could you perhaps give us a specific example of what you want to do, and why 'this' won't work for you?

Comment: I have an exercise in school which must use the professor's code. I have a more efficient way to solve the problem if I can have the supplied object reference itself (it is an item in a linked list), but I can't modify it or add any methods. It does not have a setter function and sets its variables upon creation only.

Comment: There's no way to manipulate the `SuperObject` with out setting it to itself? That seems kind of odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cant.  If you want to set the object as one of its members, you should look for another method that allows you to set that member, and pass the object in to that method:

```
MyObject mObj = new MyObject(null);
mObj.setSomeFieldThatMyObjectIsInstanceOf(mObj);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why? The object already has 'this': it doesn't need anything else.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I don't want to modify the code in the class.

Comment: What you are asking is inherently impossible. The result of the RHS is only available after it completes, which is too late to be supplying arguments to it. That applies to any function call, not just a constructor.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty much what I expected. I was just hoping Java had some sort of workaround. I won't mark yours right since this wasn't the actual answer. Sorry!

Comment: Wasn't the actual answer how?

Answer (score 2):

Inside `SuperObject` you can directly reference itself by using the keyword `this`. You don't need to pass it inside constructor..